# FLEX Video player - play count

Tags: apache-flex, math, video, dynamic, count

I have a video player in flex which constantly plays a movie. Is there a way to see how many times it has played?

So each time the movie is played, text filled populates with +1.

Thanks, Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a variable and an event handler for the complete event of the VideoPlayer and have the variable increment each time the complete event fires.
...

```
var playCount:int = 0;

protected function onPlayerComplete(event:TimeEvent):void
{
    playCount++;
}
```